# Apollo-fetch GraphQL Request

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, graphql-js

I am quite new to GraphQL I am struggling to fetch my data from my API on front-end.

I am using `apollo-fetch` to build the query and make the request, which is

```
const fetch = createApolloFetch({
  uri: `${BASE_API_URL}/graphql`,
});
fetch({
  query: `{
    transactions(limit: 3) {
      tid
      terminalNo
      issuerId
    }
  }`,
}).then(res => {
  console.log('res', res);
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I am receiving this error:`"Syntax Error: Expected Name, found String "query""`.

The weird thing is that using Postman, with pretty much the same Query I receive the correct data.

this is the query I am using on postman

```
query {
  transactions(limit: 3) {
   tid
   terminalNo
   issuerId
 }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here ? I tried some variations on the query, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was using plain javascript, not sure yet why apollo-fetch was having the error

```
fetch(`${BASE_API_URL}/graphql`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: `query {
    transactions(limit: 3, offset: 0) {
      tid
      terminalNo
      issuerId
    } 
  }`,
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => (
  this.setState({ transactions: res.data.transactions })
))
.catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Hope it helps anyone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your query string does not have the keyword query and also has an additional bracket. It should be as follows

```
fetch({
  query: `
   query transactions {
     transactions(limit: 3) {
      tid
      terminalNo
      issuerId
     }
    }
`,
})
```

Comment: same result. This was my first attempt. not the comma as well.

Comment: I've corrected the answer. My bad didn't notice your query string

Comment: still the same problem